# On the order of elements of the generating set?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

My question is only for the abelian case. The following example is to clarify the idea in the non-abelian case.

The dihedral group has the following presentation $$D_{2i}=\left<s,r/s^2=r^i=e,sr=r^{-1}s \right>$$
Order of $D_{2i}$ is $2i$. If we take $S=\{s,r\}$ and $H=\{s,sr\}$, then  $D_{2i}=\left<S \right>=\left<H\right>$, but sum order of elements of $S$ is $2+i$ and of $H$ is $4$. From this, we deduce that there is no relation between the order of the non-abelian group and the orders of elements in the generating set.

My question is there any relation between the order of **abelian** group and the order of elements in its  generating sets?

I guess the following is true $S=\{s_1,\ldots,s_k\}$ is a generating set of abelian group $G$ then $\Pi_{i=1}^k order(s_i) \geq order(G)$.

> Is this equation true, and are there any other relations?

Comment: Duplicate by the same author http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481178/oder-of-elements-of-the-generating-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation 
$$ \tag 1 \def\ord{\operatorname{ord}}\prod_i \ord s_i \ge \ord G$$ 
is true, for a proof note that given $g \in G = \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<s_1, \ldots, s_n>$, we can write 
$$ g = \prod_i s_i^{a_i(g)} $$
for some $a_i(g) \in \{0, \ldots, \ord s_i - 1\}$. This gives a one-to-one map $a = (a_1, \ldots, a_n) : G \to \prod_i \{0,\ldots, \ord s_i - 1\}$, hence we have (1).